# Is it possible to send near tokens from smart contract to other account iof I write smart contract in near-sdk-as ?If yes , which module I should use?

Tags: nearprotocol, near

While I was exploring near-sdk-as I did not find any function / APIs in sdk to send near tokens to caller of the smart contract. I am curious if there is any function to do what I have mentioned or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert when it comes to assembly script but it looks like what you can do is create a `ContractPromiseBatch` and then invoke the `.transfer` function as shown in this example here:

https://github.com/near-examples/cross-contract-calls/blob/a589ab817835f837201f4afa48be5961d8ce5360/contracts/10.linkdrop/src/10/assembly/index.ts#L93